# Post page in Asp.NET web forms when using friendly urls

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hello can you please tell why this syntax doesnt works when im using FriendlyUrls :

Page 1 :

```
<asp:Button runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Src/Verify.aspx" Text="Se Connecter"/>
```

Page 2 :

```
 var holder = PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("MainContent");

 var login = ((TextBox)holder.FindControl("login")).Text;

 var password = ((TextBox)holder.FindControl("password")).Text;
```

and maybe what can i use instead

Comment: What's not working? Be more specific please, take a moment to add more detail.